# MS Office & WebDAV Server Engine for .NET

Tags: webdav

On this website, http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/ms_office_read_only, it states that in order to open a writable version of a MS Office doc this condition has to be met:

> 1. Your WebDAV server must be configured on site root.

Is this still true? Because I tried the SqlStorage sample and it works fine. I deployed the application on IIS 7, under <server>/TestWebDav and MS Office 2010 opened the documents in the sample just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested IT Hit WebDAV Server Engine in a non-root configuration. I was using MS Office 2010 on Windows 7 as a client. I have tested Basic authentication and Anonymous.

In both cases everything worked well. MS Office was able to open a file in a read-write mode, file was saved successfully back to server after editing. 'Save As' works with no problem. All file operations worked in Windows Explorer.

However using Fiddler tool I have found that 2 requests were sent to website root: one OPTIONS (my IIS server, not webdav, returned 200 OK) and one PROPFIND request (my IIS server server returned 405 Method Not Allowed).

In general I can conclude that with MS Office 2010 on Windows 7 WebDAV works in non-root configuration.

Comment: PROPFIND request (my IIS server server returned 405 Method Not Allowed) - I was just running the integration tests and got the same error and the only test that failed is #4 - Microsoft Office discovery. I think the client simply checks the paths included in the request. First http://localhost, then http://localhost/LocalWebDav and so on. http://localhost is handled by IIS but the next one is handled by my app and it works